# Background fetch executes only once ios7

Tags: ios7, background-process

Excuse me for my silly question, But I can't understand how the background fetch is being called in ios7.  Here is the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:20];
    return YES;
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"Fetch called");
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1;
}
```

The problem is that I've set the interval to 20 seconds, but it executes only once. Such behavior looks strange to me. Maybe I'm wrong and the simulation of background fetch executes it only once by the default, but on the real device it will do it periodically. How can I be sure that it will be called every 20 seconds?? Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

What you're setting is the minimum fetch interval, which is the amount of time that must elapse before background fetch can be triggered again. After that point, iOS determines when to actually trigger background fetch using heuristics that estimate when the user is likely to open the app.